# AppEngine Push to Deploy and Modules

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine

Can I use AppEngines "Push to Deploy" (deploying by pushing a GIT repository) to update a multiple module Python application?

Where do I get the repo url for the non default modules?

Comment: I created an [issue in GAE's issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9676) a while ago, and it was resolved as "Won't fix". They suggested me to use [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) instead of modules... Still think it's just a workaround

Comment: I don:t meant a multi module GIT application. Just multiple AppEngine modules (the backend succcessor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lack of support for App Engine modules is a known issue for the push-to-deploy feature, and is something we're actively working on addressing at this time.